# Retrieve iPhone UDID on Safari

Tags: iphone, safari

There is a great instruction for retrieving iPhone UDID on Safari.

http://www.bendytree.com/tips/Getting-an-iPhone-UDID-from-Mobile-Safari

I read this article carefully and follow it.

here is my script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>URL</key>
            <string>http://appfree.com/user/retrieve.php</string>
            <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>IMEI</string>
                <string>ICCID</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>AppFree, Inc.</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>AppFree</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>9CF421B3-9853-4454-BC8A-982CBD3C907C</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>kr.co.gpon.profile-service</string>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>This temporary profile will be used to find and display your current device's UDID.</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However, it still shows **Unsigned message** when the user tries to install the profile.

PS. Is there a alternative manual to work this issue?

==========================================================================

## UPDATE

I successfully get data from my iPhone through this code.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$plistBegin   = '<?xml version="1.0"';
$plistEnd   = '</plist>';

$pos1 = strpos($data, $plistBegin);
$pos2 = strpos($data, $plistEnd);

$data2 = substr ($data,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1);

$xml = xml_parser_create();

xml_parse_into_struct($xml, $data2, $vs);
xml_parser_free($xml);

$UDID = "";
$CHALLENGE = "";
$DEVICE_NAME = "";
$DEVICE_PRODUCT = "";
$DEVICE_VERSION = "";
$iterator = 0;

$arrayCleaned = array();

foreach($vs as $v){

    if($v['level'] == 3 && $v['type'] == 'complete'){
    $arrayCleaned[]= $v;
    }
$iterator++;
}

$data = "";

$iterator = 0;

foreach($arrayCleaned as $elem){
                $data .= "\n==".$elem['tag']." -> ".$elem['value']."<br/>";
                switch ($elem['value']) {
                    case "CHALLENGE":
                        $CHALLENGE = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];
                        break;
                    case "DEVICE_NAME":
                        $DEVICE_NAME = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];
                        break;
                    case "PRODUCT":
                        $DEVICE_PRODUCT = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];
                        break;
                    case "UDID":
                        $UDID = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];
                        break;
                    case "VERSION":
                        $DEVICE_VERSION = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];
                        break;                       
                    }
                    $iterator++;
}

$params = "UDID=".$UDID."&CHALLENGE=".$CHALLENGE."&DEVICE_NAME=".$DEVICE_NAME."&DEVICE_PR ODUCT=".$DEVICE_PRODUCT."&DEVICE_VERSION=".$DEVICE_VERSION;
// enrollment is a directory
header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/enrollment?'.$params);
```

However, I faced with new obstacle.

========================================================================

I read this article and follow what he has done.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3089948?start=0&tstart=0

========================================================================
[image]

The data was sent to my server, but it stills shows the message "Invalid Profile".

It doesn't redirect to mobile website.

Comment: Jake, I have facing the same problem. Please ,can you tell me how you create this .moblieconfig and write code get UDID of device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add the

```
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/Results?data=".rawurlencode($data));
```

at the end of your code?

---

```
openssl smime \
-sign \
-signer your-cert.pem \
-inkey your-priv-key.pem \
-certfile TheCertChain.pem \
-nodetach \
-outform der \
-in ConfigProfile.mobileconfig \
-out ConfigProfile_signed.mobileconfig
```

The files you’ll need are:

your-cert.pem – this is the certificate you’ve been issued

your-priv-key.pem – this is your private key

TheCertChain.pem – this is the certificate chain (optional, in some cases)

ConfigProfile.mobileconfig – This is the unsigned copy of your configuration profile

more detailed [here](https://confluence.terena.org/display/tcs/Sign+Apple+mobileconfig+files)

Comment: yeah I put header code at the end. header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/enrollment?'.$params);

Comment: I feel like header code helps to move the screen back to the website, but it won't work somehow :(

Comment: do you have it on the public access? so I could trace the requests?

Comment: unfortunately, I am running local server. Have you tried this one before?

Comment: that's the thing :( I can't find a instruction to sign my profile.

Comment: Do I have use Go Daddy Secure Signing Certificate? http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx

Comment: I know this comes late, but just in case... I create my custom mobileconfig file that installs fine if I don't sign it. But after signing it (following the instructions in this answer), if I try to install through safari it gives an error. I checked content-type and it is correct. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: can you send output log please?